# How to click on Radio button with only a class name Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, radio-button

I am trying to click on this radio button.

```
 <form id = "co-payment-form" class = "payment" action ="">
    <dt>
    <label class="radio" for="p_method_checkoutdotcom">
    <span class="radio__span">
    <i class="radio__icon"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="radio__title">Credit Card </span>
    </label>
    </dt>
```

I target it with the code:

> IWebElement creditcardRadio = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("radio__span"));

I get the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll Additional information: Unexpected error. Element is not clickable at point (297.3999938964844, 302.5). Other element would receive the click: `<div class="loader loader--white-transparent loader--fixed"></div>`

Note, there are a few other radio buttons in this group. To view it, just fill out this page https://shop.adidas.ae/en/checkout/onepage/ until you get to the **Credit card, Paypal or on delivery** radio buttons

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

According to the error description, there is a "loader" overlay shown above the element when you try to click it. *Wait for the element to be clickable* and then perform the click:

```
IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.ClassName("radio__span")));
element.Click();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I am still getting the error:

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: Unexpected error. Element is not clickable at point (297.3999938964844, 302.5). Other element would receive the click: <div class="loader loader--white-transparent loader--fixed"></div>

Comment: Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: @SamM this is strange, I don't think you should be getting this kind of error again. Are you sure you are not trying to click this element before the wait? Also, does maximizing the browser window make any difference? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah it's weird, the browser is maximized. If you want to test yourself follow this link https://shop.adidas.ae/en/checkout/onepage/ and just follow all the info until you get to the radio button page.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Actions.
Move to that element and then trigger a click. It should do the trick.

Something like this:
**in java**
Actions clickOnRadioButton = new Actions(driver);
clickOnRadioButton.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i.radio__icon")).click().build().perform();